# Drag Down UIView in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, uigesturerecognizer

I saw in my iPhone app that there is a gesture on the status bar which can access Notification Center. How can I implement that kind of transition in my app?. I think this is done with the swipe gesture recognizer, but how do I include a swipe gesture from top to bottom (how you can drag the Notification Center through its full transition)? Is there any sample code or something that can help me do this?
Thaks in advance

Comment: That's the Notification Center. Since that's a system wide gesture, if you implemented something like that in your app, I suspect either a) Apple would reject it because it conflicts with Notification Center or b) your users wouldn't see it because the notification center would appear.

Comment: @tomasmcguinness Te question's not about implementing a 2nd notification center, but about implementing a user interaction like this.

Comment: @tomasmcguinness ,no no,,i just want to show a uiview controller like that,,that alll...

Comment: @Kai yess,corret,how to get swipe gesture from top to bottom?there is left and right swipe available...

Comment: @stackiphone I won't use a swipe gesture recognizer at all, see my answer below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Should be easy to do. Let's say you have a `UIView` (`mainView`) from which you want to trigger the pull down thing.

1. Put a subview (`pulldownView`) on mainView top-outside of visible area.
2. Implement `touchesBegan` on `mainView` and check if the touch is in the top 30 pixels (or points).
3. Implement `touchesMoved` where you check, if move direction is down and `pulldownView` not visible and if so drag the `pulldownView` down into visible area of main view or check if move direction is up and `pulldownView` visible and if so push upwards out of visible area.
4. Implement `touchesEnd` where you end the drag or push movement by checking in which direction the `pulldownView` was moved.

EDIT:

Here's some sample code. Untested, may contain typos, maybe won't compile, but should contain the essential part needed.

```
//... inside mainView impl:
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  UITouch *touch = (UITouch *)[touches anyObject];
  start = [touch locationInView:self.superview].y;
  if(start > 30 && pulldownView.center.y < 0)//touch was not in upper area of view AND pulldownView not visible
  {
    start = -1; //start is a CGFloat member of this view
  }
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  if(start < 0)
  {
    return;
  }
  UITouch *touch = (UITouch *)[touches anyObject];
  CGFloat now = [touch locationInView:self.superview].y;
  CGFloat diff = now - start;
  directionUp = diff < 0;//directionUp is a BOOL member of this view
  float nuCenterY = pulldownView.center.y + diff;
  pulldownView.center = CGPointMake(pulldownView.center.x, nuCenterY);
  start = now;
}


-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  if (directionUp)
  {
    //animate pulldownView out of visibel area
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.3 animations:^{pulldownView.center = CGPointMake(pulldownView.center.x, -roundf(pulldownView.bounds.size.height/2.));}];
  }
  else if(start>=0)
  {
    //animate pulldownView with top to mainviews top
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.3 animations:^{pulldownView.center = CGPointMake(pulldownView.center.x, roundf(pulldownView.bounds.size.height/2.));}];
  }
}
```

Comment: ,,thanks for your answer,,but am very new able to iOS,,so i think its not easy for me..lets try it...if there any sample ode or something u know,,that will be easer for me...thanks

Comment: @Kai's solution should work. I'd encourage you to think a little bit about how that functionality is going to work with Notification Center in your app, and whether it will be non-intuitive to your user or difficult to use. For instance, Android has a similar notification center functionality; in addition, you pull the screen down slightly in the browser to get to the address bar. It can be difficult to get to the address bar in the browser without accidentally getting the notification center instead. This may work fine in your app, just something to think about.

Comment: @stackiphone added some sample code which might need some adjustments

Answer (score 1):

You can implement UISwipeGestureRecognizer to handle swipe gestures in your app, and specify the direction of the swipe to detect as UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown.

There's an [Apple sample here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleGestureRecognizers/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009460). There are also some [WWDC10 sessions](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/) that are worth a look. I'd suggest "Simplifying Touch Event Handling with Gesture Recognizers" and "Advanced Gesture Recognition" from [that page](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/).

Comment: yes corret,thanks for your answer..i know how to implement the swipe gestue,,but how can i show that view like this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by just using a subclassed `UIView` in a full sized `UIScrollView`. The `UIView` passes touch events to its underlaying view if the user touches a point that is not "dragabble".

```
@implementation MyCustomUIView

- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    // Check whether we are on the overlay
    if
    (
        point.y < 460.0f
        // Maybe some more restrictions here
    )
    {
        // Block the event, pass to parent
        return NO;
    }

    // Everything okay
    return YES;
}

@end
```

This code makes the `UIScrollView` only respond to touches under 460px. If your `UIScrollView` for example 800px height, you can touch it from 460px to 800px. Enough to open, close and use it. So if you got a full sized `UIScrollView`, you can drag it up to open it while you are able to "touch" the underlaying view. The benefit of this method is that all animations relay on the default behaviour and you dont have to implement it yourself.