# Set "Touchable" area of UIScrollView

Tags: ios, webview, uiscrollview, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a main menu with a list of buttons. On the bottom I have a bar that the user can flick up to the top via a scrollview. Whats underneath that bar however is a uiwebview. So when the user tries to scroll in the uiwebview, the bar and webview just snaps back down. Also, the uibuttons won't work when the bar is down because the scrollview is sitting over them. How do i make the scroll only work when the user touches the bar and make the buttons on my menu work when the bar is down?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Please share some codes so we can see what you did and offer some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you want the scrollView to "work" (maybe when user flicks the bar up) have the following code:

```
scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

and wherever you don't want the scrollView to register any user actions (like when the bar is down) just do the opposite and set it to NO.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly, you want the `UIScrollView` to respond to touches in only a certain part of the frame (the bar)?

I would suggest taking a look at one of my previous answers to a similar problem, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17823055/1367622).

In particular, see:

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10365223/1367622) to the SO question [Touch and pull down a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690964/touch-and-pull-down-a-view). It uses the `hitTest:withEvent:` method to determine whether the scrollview responds to a touch or leaves it for the view under it to respond to.
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14212534/1367622) to the question [Drag Down UIView in iOS 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317951/drag-down-uiview-in-ios-5) works in a similar way, using `pointInside:withEvent:` to make the `UIScrollView` only respond to touches in a given area.
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4961492/1367622) to the question [Event handling for iOS - how hitTest:withEvent: and pointInside:withEvent: are related?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961386/event-handling-for-ios-how-hittestwithevent-and-pointinsidewithevent-are-r) gives a good overview of how `hitTest:withEvent:` and `pointInside:withEvent:` work together.