# animating constraints changes the margin

Tags: swift2, constraints, uiviewanimation

In my app i want to show a view coming from bottom. So for that i have animated the bottom constraints. The animation works fines but the issue is that the margin is not proper

original view

[image]

[image]

The issues is that the buttons are not in center

Code

```
let translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -(view.frame.height/2 - view.center.y/4 + 20))
        let scale =  CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.7, 0.7);
        let transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(translate, scale)


        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.6, delay: 0, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.ivLogo.transform = transform
            }, completion:nil)



        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        //self.loginSignUpView.layoutIfNeeded()
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: {

            self.loginSignUpBottomConst.constant=30
            self.loginSignUpView.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.view.layoutMarginsDidChange()
            }, completion: nil)


    }
```

Comment: Could you show what the view looks like before the animation? And why do you change the transform? Your question only said you want to move views upwards.

Comment: yes the the bottom 3 buttons will come from bottom

Comment: AutoLayout shouldn't be mixed with other layout tenichques (like directly setting frame, origin and transform), otherwise the layout behavior would be unexpected. If you just want to move views, animating the bottom constraint  would suffice. Remove the first animation and see if any unpected behavior occurs.

Comment: yes i did tat also but same thing, or else can you suggest me other way how  i can animate view from bottom

Comment: Animate just a single constraint will do it. I don't understand why you change the transform. And can you post an image of what the views looks like before the animation?

Comment: i have edited my post

Comment: Still not understand your intent with the images. Where does the logo go and why the width of the screen changes during the animation?

Comment: you can simply do it by `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: {
            self.loginSignUpBottomConst.constant=30
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })` .. no need of other code something like http://stackoverflow.com/a/32516167/4601170

Comment: i used this but still its moving out of center